# Calculation of conductivity, some integral question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, greens-functions

I have some questions of the integral when I  calculate the conductivity.
The integral actually is as the following form:

$$\frac{1}{L^3}\sum_{p} p^2 G_{p}(\epsilon^-) G_{p}(\epsilon^+ +w) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}p^2 \frac{1}{\epsilon -\frac{p^2}{2m}-i\gamma} \frac{1}{\epsilon +w-\frac{p^2}{2m}+i\gamma}$$

Firstly, the integral is linear divergent due to power counting of p, however, the solution (page 398) of *Condensed Matter Field Theory* written by *Alexander Altland, Ben Simons* is performed by making some approximations, then we can get a finite result, i.e. $\frac{1}{2\gamma-iw}$ , this makes me puzzled.

Secondly, if I complete a contour integration with a cut-line and omit the integration on $C_R$ where R goes to Infinity (actually, this part contribute to a divergent term ), then I can get the same result.

So My first question is how to abandon the divergent terms systematically and then get a physical result.
My second question is what is the relation between my solution and the solution of  the textbook, is it just a curious coincidence?

Comment: In practice, the divergence can be avoided by imposing a UV cutoff on $p$, since we are interested in just the low-energy behaviors.

Comment: yeah, but how to drop the cutoff dependence in our final result?